# How do you select a record in a form and show calculations based on that record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, post

I need to know how you could make a form where you can select a record, do some calculations based on that record and display the results (preferably on the same page).

To make it as simple as possible let's say I want to select a record from the User model and show his capitalized email.

So the structure would be:

**capitalized_controller.rb**

```
class CapitalizedController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def users
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

**capitalized/users.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_tag('/capitalized/users') do %>
    <div class="controls">
        <%= select_tag :email, options_from_collection_for_select(@users, "id", "email"), :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= submit_tag nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And it's being displayed like this:
[image: Blur]

So, until here it shows me a list of the user's emails sorted alphabetically and I can hit the send button ("Enviar") and it works perfect (I have no errors so far), but it only load the page again, what should I do to show the capitalized email?

Comment: you have two options, either you use AJAX or if you already have everything your need to make those calculations in your user model, then hide that info, and show it/hide it with javascript. Whatever you want. Rails has some form helpers to build ajax forms. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end the only thing I had to do was this:

**capitalized_controller.rb**

```
class CapitalizedController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def users
    @users = User.all

    if params[:user]
      @result = User.all.find(params[:user])
      @result = @result.email.capitalize!
    else
      @result = nil
    end
  end
end
```

**capitalized/users.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_tag('/capitalized/users', :method => "post", id: "capitalize-form") do %>
    <div class="controls">
        <%= select_tag :user, options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, "id", "email", params[:user]), :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= submit_tag 'Capitalize email', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% if @result %>
    <p><%= @result %></p>
<% end %>
```

And it's being displayed like this:

[image: Capitalized email]

Answer (score 0):

In your controller change this:

```
def users
  @users = User.all
  @var_to_show_user =  User.search(params[:search_user])
end
```

In yor model do this:

```
def self.search(search_mail)  
  if search  
    where('mail = ?', search_mail )  
  else  
    scoped  
  end  
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= form_tag('/capitalized/users') do %>
   <div class="controls"><%= select_tag :email, options_from_collection_for_select(@users, "id", "email"), :class => 'text_field' %></div>
   <div class="form-actions"><%= submit_tag nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %></div>
<% end %>

<% @var_to_show_user.each do |result| %>
  <%= result.mail.to_s.first.upcase   %>
<% end %>
```

NOTICE:

```
"mail" is the column's name

"to_s" is to convert to string

"first" is to show the first letter

"upcase" is to show the value capitalize
```

Hope this works...and good luck.